# Can we use Web Farm and Web Garden together?

Tags: asp.net, web-farm, web-garden

Web farm is used for multiple request and multiple user using switching among them.

Web Garden creates worker processes for every processor individually for one user.

Is it possible to use worker process as a switch and convert it into Web Farm that can allocate multiple processor on bases of algorithm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my point of view (and please correct me if I mistake)

the practical diferent betwing web farm and web garden is that the web farm is a plan running on many computers, and web garden is a plan running on a single machine.

**You do not need from my point of view to try to convert web garden to web farm, is with out any point. (please correct me if I mistake)**

If you have one machine, and you open more than 1 worker process on Web Garden iis settings, then you only need to make your setup running as web farm, have one database connect, use mutex or other lock for be sure that 2 or more worker process are synchronize together.

In my application I have use them both and my only issue is the synchronization of the data.